# How to find all internal website traffic to a particular page in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I currently trying to check some stats in google analytics, but have run into a few difficulties.

I want to see how many landed on my site (any page) and then visited a specific page. I'm only interested in internal site traffic. So I don't want to know how many people landed at the specific page directly. I only want to know about them if they first landed somewhere else on the site and clicked through to a specific page.

For example say my site is:

www.mysite.com

And the page i want to know about is www.mysite.com/awesome/

I want to know all of the people that arrived at www.mysite.com, www.mysite.com/page, www.mysite.com/anyothepage/ etc... and then went on to visit www.mysite.com/awesome/

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably be better answered on the [GA forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/analytics), since it's not really a programming question, but you could create a custom report to show you this data.

Here's an example of how you could build it:

**Metrics**: Pageviews, any other things you want (Bounce Rate, etc.)

**Dimension Drilldowns**: Previous Page Path

**Filters**:

Include: Page: Exact: /awesome/

Include: Previous Page Path: Regex: ^/.*

You might need to tweak those filters based on your actual page names / paths.